# Break a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m trying to break a JSON object. This doesn’t work, please guide.

```js
var mock_data = {
  "available": [{
    "UserID": 7,
    "UserName": "Manoj",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 9,
    "TimeLimit": 4.0
  }, {
    "UserID": 5,
    "UserName": "Thisun",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 9,
    "TimeLimit": 4.0
  }, {
    "UserID": 6,
    "UserName": "Isuru",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 7,
    "TimeLimit": 4.0
  }, {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "UserName LastName",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 6,
    "TimeLimit": 6.0
  }],
  "selected": [{
    "UserID": 7,
    "UserName": "Manoj",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 9,
    "TimeLimit": 4.0
  }, {
    "UserID": 5,
    "UserName": "Thisun",
    "Language": "Java",
    "Score": 9,
    "TimeLimit": 4.0
  }]
};

$(mock_data.available).each(function(i, value) {

  $('.risktable').append('<tr>' +
    '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + value.UserName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + value.Language + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + value.Score + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + value.TimeLimit + '</td>' +
    '</tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="risktable">

</table>
```

Above does not produce any output. Is there anything wrong with the loop?

Comment: break into what? can you share the output you want?

Comment: Did you call jquery script?

Comment: i want to append the data into a table.

Comment: If you load jQuery then it works. Edit the snippet and change `No jQuery` to `jQuery 2.1`.

Comment: '$' is not defined. Did you load jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried to click "Run code snippet"? It works for me...

Comment: It works. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/2dgub4tx/)

Comment: You might want to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ .

Comment: @Yeldar: The snippet was modified by Xufox to load jQuery. It didn't work before.

Comment: I had the assumption that you just forgot to include jQuery in the snippet. But after including it there, I can’t seem to reproduce your problem. Voting to close as non-reproducible. The answer by user3089871 should cover any possible problem.

Comment: It works, my mistake. didn't load jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/advjeN
I tried your code it's working.

did you put the Jquery CDN ? if not, put this in your header :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Did you put your code into a jquery function ? if not :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    [YOUR CODE HERE]

});
```